# ¿Que significa ':> /archivoDebug.log' en bash?

Tags: bash, shell

En lo que llevo con bash es la primera vez que me encuentro con esto y no se que hace esta convinacion de `:>`, si me pueden explicar por favor esta linea:

```sh
:> /archivoDebug.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es una combinación, el `:` es un comando (específicamente, un "special shell builtin"). No es `:>` sino `:` y `>`, y en este caso, es totalmente inútil. Aquí se usa para crear un archivo vacío, pero podrían haber hecho exactamente lo mismo sin ningun comando ya que `> /archivoDebug.log` (es decir, `>` y un nombre) crea un archivo vacío sin necesitar ningun comando. No se porque mucha gente hacen cosas como `: > foo` o `true > foo` o `touch foo` dado que `> foo` funciona igual (en bash, aunque no en otros shells).

Mas en detalle, el `:` se llama "NULL command" y es parte de las versiones de POSIX mas nuevas. En general funciona de manera equivalente al `true`, es un comando que se usa cuando quieres un comando que sea siempre exitoso. Por ejemplo para montar un bucle infinito:

```
while true; do commando; done
```

o

```
while : ; do comando; done
```

Anteriormente, solo teníamos el `true` aunque los dos son sutilmente diferentes. [POSIX dice](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/true.html):

> The true utility has been retained in this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, even though the shell special built-in : provides similar functionality, because true is widely used in historical scripts and is less cryptic to novice script readers.

En la practica, hay solo una diferencia entre `:` y `true` que yo sepa: en un POSIX sh, por ejemplo en `dash` o `bash --posix`, funcionan de manera diferente con la asignación de variables:

```
$ dash
$ x=foo true
$ echo "x es: $x"
x es:
```

En cambio:

```
$ dash
$ x=foo :   
$ echo "x es: $x"
x es: foo
```

Pero en `bash`, creo que son equivalentes, aunque distintos (ninguno de los dos no es alias del otro).

Comment: tiene rezon `> archivo` crea un archivo en bash, el problema es que en otras shells como zsh si es necesario anteponer `:`, `true` o hacerlo con `touch`.

Comment: Ah! Gracias, @AgileSoul, que raro que no funciona ya que en un shell posix como `dash` si que funciona. Parece que `zsh` es la excepción y se queda esperando datos

Answer (score 2):

los 2 puntos son solo un alias para true

en tu ejemplo la redireccion se hace a pesar de que no hay un comando a redireccionar

```
:> /archivoDebug.log
```

pero como : es true seria igual a decir **true> /archivoDebug.log**

se usa mas para pasar un archivo a 0 bytes.

esto tambien ayuda a que no se genere un correo al momento de la ejecucion del archivo

algo como hacer un **/dev/null 2>&1** que convierte un error estadar a una salida estandar pero una forma mas simple

Comment: Un comentario tiquismiquis: el `:` no es un alias, y ni si quera es exactamente lo mismo con `true` (mira `help true` y `help :` en un bash shell). En la practica, la única diferencia es que si haces `x="foo" :`, la variable `$x` queda con su valor, pero si haces `x="foo" true`, no queda. Bueno, ¡ya dije que era un comentario tiquismiquis!